# Getting NaN values during for loops while trying to append dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse through and add data to an existing dataframe by running a function isValid(s) that returns a dictionary:

```
combo.update({"is_valid": isValid, "total_tests": ttl, "positive": pos, "negative": neg})
return combo
```

And then creating a blank dataframe, appending that dataframe with the dictionary, and then concatenating that dataframe with the previous existing dataframe. Here is my code for it:

```
def CleanCovidTest(df_test):
s = 0
df_add = pd.DataFrame()
for value in isValidString(df_test.testresults.iloc[s]):
    result = isValidString(df_test.testresults.iloc[s]) 
    df_add = df_add.append(result, ignore_index = True)                     
    s += 1
df_test = pd.concat([df_test, df_add], axis = 1)
return df_test
```

This code succeeds in adding values for the first 4 rows of the dataframe, but then it returns only NaN values:

```
index clinic      date          testresults  ...  negative positive  total_tests
0     1001  5/6/2020               R4-3+1  ...       3.0      1.0          4.0
1     1002  5/6/2020             R14-2+12  ...       2.0     12.0         14.0
2     1003  5/6/2020  R5-3+2R7+7-0R11+4-7  ...      10.0     13.0         23.0
3     1004  5/6/2020        R10-8+2R7+7-0  ...       8.0      9.0         17.0
4     1005  5/6/2020   R5-3+2R9+7-2R1+0-1  ...       NaN      NaN          NaN
...
95    1096  5/6/2020         R4-3+1R6-3+3  ...       NaN      NaN          NaN
96    1097  5/6/2020         R9-3+6R7+7-0  ...       NaN      NaN          NaN
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this? I have also tried creating yet another new dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(result, index = [s])` and appending df_add with this new dataframe instead, but I get the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your loop:

```
s = 0
df_add = pd.DataFrame()
for value in isValidString(df_test.testresults.iloc[s]):
    result = isValidString(df_test.testresults.iloc[s]) 
    df_add = df_add.append(result, ignore_index = True)                     
    s += 1
```

Variable `value` only loops over the results of `isValidString` (terrible function name, by the way) for `s==0`, and then the loop stops.

Your code is too confusing to give a solution, but look at this variation, maybe you will get inspired:

```
for s in range(len(df_test)):
    for value in isValidString(df_test.testresults.iloc[s]):
        df_add.append(value, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Sorry for the function name, it's a required function name as per the assignment. Your variation returns a TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>, but it is an improvement over my loop and I'll keep working in this direction